# iOS: Simple Retain Cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, retain-cycle

Let's say you have have a viewController with:

```
@property (strong) object* A 
@property (strong) object* B
```

You then purposely create a retain cycle at somepoint, without timers, such that

```
self.A.someStrongProperty = self  //retain cycle
```

**Question:** Suppose the VC containing these properties gets deallocated, could a retain cycle or memory leak persist?

Comment: ... That is a simple assignment, no retain cycle.

Comment: sorry let me rephrase

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have posted above, there is no retain cycle.

A retain cycle would be `self.A = self;` or more likely, `self.A.someStrongProperty = self`.

**Edit:** In the case you have edited above, assuming `self` is a view controller, it would not deallocate because of the retain cycle. You should change your `someStrongProperty` to be a `weak` property, which will prevent the retain cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in case you retain `self` you are causing a retain cycle.

This will cause the `self` instance not to be deallocated, causing a memory leak.

To prevent this, you can either use a `weak` property or manually setting `someStrongProperty` to `nil` at some point, in order to break the retain cycle.

Comment: `-setA:` will strongly retain `B` while assigning `_A = B`, which is not an issue.

Comment: First of all, this is ARC and `_A = B` does retain `B`. Second, `A` is a pointer to an object `*A`, and `B` is a pointer to an object `*B`. All `self.A = self.B` does is release `*A` and retain `*B`.

Comment: I'm talking about the setter implementation when referring to `_A = B`. What will happen is something like `[_A release]; _A = [self.B retain];` which will cause `B` to be sent a `retain` message.

Comment: So yes, we are saying the same thing. `A` will be holding a strong reference to `*B`, but oviously no cycle is created.

Comment: Yes, A becomes a strong reference to B. I thought you were saying the object originally at A retained the object at B during that assignment. Glad we cleared that up.

Comment: Absolutely not, my bad. Poor choice of terms indeed, I'm glad too.